# MYSQL: Create Unique ID based on Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have the following column in database:

```
Email 
aaa@gmail.com
ccc@gmail.com
ddd@gmail.com
ccc@gmail.com
bbb@gmail.com
aaa@gmail.com
```

I would like to ALTER THE TABLE and create a unique ID column based on the 'Email' column. Like the following:

```
Email           Email_ID
aaa@gmail.com   001
ccc@gmail.com   002
ddd@gmail.com   003
ccc@gmail.com   002
bbb@gmail.com   004
aaa@gmail.com   001
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: _"It needs to be auto-increment, **primary key**, unsigned, zerofill, and **unique**"_  your example does not meet these requirements. Also zero-fill is purely presentational, you don't need formatting in your stored data

Comment: Thank you Phil - it appears you understand what I need, so I think an answer would be more helpful than chastising my poor example

Comment: _"it appears you understand what I need"_ Well no, not really. An example matching your desired result would go a long way towards getting a good answer

Comment: OK, make believe that I never said any of those additional requirements. I have edited my original post. I just need what it clearly laid out in the example above.

Comment: What should happen if records are removed? Say you remove all `ccc@gmail.com` entries; should the `ddd` records remain with id `003` or should they move up to `002`?

Comment: the ddd should remain with id 003

Comment: Are these records associated with any other data or is it literally just this one table with one column? I ask as this would work a lot better normalised into a table where `Email` is unique and `Email_ID` is just an auto-incremented integer primary key. You could then reference this normalised table with foreign keys and easily create your desired result with a query or view

Comment: Just this one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use an integer for the value -- rather than a string.  Then, you can use variables as for the assignment:

```
alter table t add email_id int;

update t join
       (select email, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
        from (select distinct email from t order by email) t cross join
             (select @rn := 0) params
       ) tt
       on t.email = tt.email
    set t.email_id = tt.rn;
```

If you run the subquery, you will see that this assigns to each email a distinct number.

The outer query then assigned this number into the `email_id` column.  In MySQL 8+, you could also write:

```
alter table t add email_id int;

update t join
       (select email, row_number() over (order by email) as rn
        from (select distinct email from t order by email) t 
       ) tt
       on t.email = tt.email
    set t.email_id = tt.rn;
```

Comment: Gordon, would you mind explaining step-by-step what is going on in your code, so that I can understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL version 8 or later, then `DENSE_RANK` provides a nice option here:

```
SELECT
    Email,
    LPAD(CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Email) AS CHAR(3)), 3, '0') AS Email_ID
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    Email;
```

I would have suggested maybe just adding an auto increment column to your table, but that wouldn't quite meet your requirements, because an auto increment column would always be unique.

Comment: No you don't, and you should not.  What you are asking for is a presentation thing.

Comment: Yes, I do. I want to alter the table to add the unique ID

Comment: What happens when you add new records?  Do you just keep running an update over and over again?  What happens when a record gets deleted?  Do you also keep running the same update to reset the email ID?

Comment: You raise an interesting point there @TimBiegeleisen, what happens when a record is added / deleted? Your answer won't return the same values each time it's executed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What about the ZEROFILL dataype? 
*When used in conjunction with the optional (nonstandard) attribute ZEROFILL, the default padding of spaces is replaced with zeros. For example, for a column declared as INT(4) ZEROFILL, a value of 5 is retrieved as 0005.*
Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: I would like it to auto increment after my one-time add of the column

Comment: Yeah, so you can't easily do this in MySQL or most other SQL databases.  I suggest using dense rank, or an approximation to that, if you are using < MySQL 8.0.

Comment: isn't what he wants is another table with one row per email and then a view that joins the two tables.  failing that I don't see how it can auto-generate.

Comment: @Hogan I was thinking the exact same thing (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936495/mysql-create-unique-id-based-on-another-column#comment96637443_54936495))

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do...

1. Create a new table with a unique `email` column

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE `emails` (
     id INT(3) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
   );
   ```
2. Seed it with your current data

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO `emails` (`email`)
   SELECT DISTINCT `email` FROM `some_mystery_table`
   ORDER BY `email`;
   ```
3. Alter your existing tables to reference `emails(id)` as a foreign key. This could be a little tricky as you'd need to (probably)

   1. Add a new `int` column `email_id` where required
   2. Update your data with the `id` value corresponding to the email address

      ```sql
      UPDATE some_mystery_table, emails
      INNER JOIN emails ON some_mystery_table.email = emails.email
      SET some_mystery_table.email_id = emails.id;
      ```
   3. Remove the `email` column
   4. Add a foreign key where `email_id` references `emails(id)`
4. When displaying your data and you need a zero-padded email `id`, join the `emails` table, eg

   ```sql
   SELECT a.whatever, e.email, LPAD(e.id, 3, '0') AS email_id
   FROM some_mystery_table a
   INNER JOIN emails e ON a.email_id = e.id;
   ```
5. When adding new email records, you add them to `emails` first, then use the generated `id` in any other related tables.

Comment: Thank you but Gordon's solution worked for me. I couldn't believe it!

Comment: There's a reason Gordon has a 780k rep score :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE emails add column `email_id` int(5) ZEROFILL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
SET @x:=0;
UPDATE emails SET email_id = LPAD(@x:= (@x+1),4, '0') WHERE 1=1;
```

We first added the column `email_id` to the table `emails` and set it as primary key, using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE emails add column `email_id` int(5) ZEROFILL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Then we declared a global variable called x with a default value of 0:

```
SET @x:=0;
```

And finally, we filled the column with the incremental zero filled id:

```
UPDATE emails SET email_id = LPAD(@x:= (@x+1),4, '0') WHERE 1=1;
```

We used [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to zero fill.

Comment: It says "LPAD is not valid at this position, expecting a complete function call or other expression"

Comment: Sorry I had a space just before the = sign in `@x:= (@x+1)` which was causing the error. Now its fixed you may try it :)

Make sure to drop the column first or just run the code after the ALTER

Comment: While this may work, in general it is not desirable to have to run an update after each DML operation which happens to a table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we're running the update only once, to fix old data. Now on since we used the `ZEROFILL` data type, the integers will auto increment with zero fill.