# SQL unique auto-increment column in the context of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a column in the existing table with an auto-incrementing key based on `Prefix` column, with the output expected as follows:

| Prefix | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 444 | 2 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 999 | 4 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 444 | 2 |

Do you know any simple solution how to do that? I found out a solution for mysql but it is not working. I am using sql management studio with sql server

I tried solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936495/mysql-create-unique-id-based-on-another-column) but it does not work. I have errors

Comment: MySQL uses SQL...

Comment: "can convert it sql" makes no sense. "SQL" is a query language used by all relational databases - including MySQL

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us your MySQL code.

Comment: @jarlh I am reffering to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936495/mysql-create-unique-id-based-on-another-column thread and using sql server. I need exactly the same result as in mentioned thread. Please bear with me I am newbie in sql

Comment: I don't follow the problem here. Nothing in the above looks like you're talking about an `IDENTITY`. An `IDENTITY` has a always ascending value; You have multiple duplicate rows in the above (I would expect different values in one of the columns).

Comment: @Lamu column ID should be auto-incrementing only when column Prefix has a new value (without existing id), If Prefix is duplicated ID should be the same for every single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by prefix) as id
from t;
```

In SQL Server, you can phrase this as an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by prefix) as new_id
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = new_id;
```

Comment: it is working perfect! Thank you very much!!